# How to create a "Finish" button that clears all previous information and launches main activity again

Tags: java, android

My app goes from Main Activity -> 2nd Activity -> Final Activity.

I wish to create a button in Final Activity that will basically restart Main Activity like how the app was launched.

I tried looking this question up but I couldn't find an answer that was appropriate.

Would appreciate the help.

Thank you.

Comment: finishAffinity() will finish all open activities

Comment: Perhaps this should be a single activity with three fragments (or composables).